# WEKA 3.7.10 not compatible format, class index differ

Tags: machine-learning, classification, weka

I use weka for text classification, I have a train set and untagged test set, the goal is to classify test set.

In WEKA 3.6.6 everything goes well, I can select **Supplied test set** and train the model and get result.

On the same files, WEKA 3.7.10 says that

```
Train and test set are not compatible. Would you like to automatically wrap the classifier in "inputMappedClassifier" before porceeding?
```

And when I press **No** it outputs the following error message

```
Problem evaluating classfier: Train and test are not compatible Class index differ
: 2!= 0
```

I understand that the key is **Class index differ: 2!= 0.**

However what does it mean? Why it works in WEKA 3.6.6 and not compatible in WEKA 3.7.10?
How can I make the test set compatible to train set?

Answer (score 0):

When you import the supplied test set, are you selecting the same class attribute as the one that you use in the train set? If you don't change this field, weka selects the last attribute as being the class automatically.

Comment: To begin with, Welcome to StackOverflow! I won't downvote this answer, but I wanted to tell you Follow-up questions should be posted as a comment to the original question, not as an answer. Otherwise, other people can actually down vote your answer and affect your score.